# Is it important / good to convert mutables to immutables before returning them?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

If I'm using a method to return an NSArray, and inside that method I build up the result as a NSMutableArray, I'm often tempted to put `return [NSArray arrayWithArray:myMutable]` instead of `return myMutable` just to lock it up and prevent mutation by some devious other code that might check `isMemberOfClass` on it and do some mutations.

If I'm just coding for myself, and I know I will treat return values as being what they say they are, is there any reason to switch it to NSArray before returning it? Any advantage I'm not seeing here?

Comment: "When you call a method and receive an object in return, the object could be mutable even if the method’s return type characterizes it as immutable. There is nothing to prevent a class from declaring a method to return an immutable object but returning a mutable object in its implementation. Although you could use introspection to determine whether a received object is actually mutable or immutable, you shouldn’t. Always use the return type of an object to judge its mutability". From [Object Mutability](http://bit.ly/mXOexA)

Comment: Thanks, that's a good reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no real advantage in doing this; in general you should expect that clients of your interface will respect the contract of that interface.

In the case of many of the Foundation value and container types (`NSString`, etc.), it matters even less; due to an implementation detail of the toll-free bridging mechanism, both the mutable and immutable variants are actually instances of the same class. The `init` methods for NSString and NSMutableString, for example, both actually return an instance of __NSCFString, which inherits from both. This object retains the mutability or immutability of the API you called, but you can't tell by looking at the class whether it's mutable or not.

In other words, `[aString isKindOfClass:[NSMutableString class]]` will always return `YES`, regardless of whether you created a mutable object or not. As a result, using that API to check whether something is mutable or not doesn't work anyway, so there's no point in worrying whether clients of your API will try to do it.

**Edit:**
I originally stated that you couldn't tell by inspecting the class of an array whether it was mutable or not, but it turns out that in the case of `NSArray`, you can tell. (Thanks to @albertamg for catching the error.) I've changed the examples above to use `NSString`, which is a case where you really *can't* tell. In general, though, I would consider it a bug if someone treated an object you returned as mutable when it wasn't vended as such, and wouldn't worry about programming around it.

**Edit again:**
So it turns out that in some versions of OS X and iOS, you can't detect mutablility of `NSArray` either, but in more recent versions, they've changed the implementation such that you can. You still can't detect it in `NSString`, though. The lesson to take home from all of this, then, is that you shouldn't be using `isKindOfClass:` on objects that are part of a [class cluster](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/ClassCluster.html).

Comment: `isMemberOfClass` retuns `NO` because `NSArray` is a class cluster and what you get when you create one is an instance of a subclass. `isKindOfClass` will yield the expected result (including testing for mutability).

Comment: I do want `isMemberOfClass`, you're right. But the point about mutability stands; it will return YES either way.

Comment: You're right; I did just try it. what I said was true of NSString, though; I'll change my example to use NSString instead. Thanks for catching the error.

Comment: I guess it depends (iOS vs Mac). You are right on the Mac, it does return `YES` either way, but on iOS `[anArray isKindOfClass:[NSMutableArray class]]` will return NO if the array is immutable.

Comment: On 10.7, you can detect mutability in arrays with `isKindOfClass`; but I could have sworn you couldn't in 10.6. Maybe they changed it in iOS at some point, and it's just now propogating its way to OS X.

Comment: +1 I appreciate you took my comments into consideration. I'm on 10.6, I can confirm that you can't.

Comment: Wow this brings up a lot I didn't know about immutable and mutable objects, isMemberOfClass and isKindOfClass always seemed to me to be almost bad practice, now I know it's almost suicide.

Comment: Doh. I just realized that in my first comment I said `isMemberOfClass`, when I really meant `isKindOfClass` to agree with albertamg.

Answer (score 2):

I've been writing a category for NSArray which contains purely functional methods and returning immutable objects based on the original array is a must. But I wouldn't bother in any other context. Maybe as an idiot-proofing measure in a Framework for public consumption.

If you're trying to mutate the immutable somewhere in your code path you probably have a problem that shouldn't be rectified by 'putting down the barrier' so to speak.

Answer (score 1):

Not really, if you are writing a library and you want to protect the array from begin changed of cause it is a good idea, it depends on how closely connect the two parts of code are, returning a NSArray instead of a NSMutableArray is a good practice for catching possible errors, but of cause creating a new array takes CPU cycles, you have to basically make the call yourself based on the situation, I tend to like to take it safe in situation like this, I will often add NSParameterAsserts in my code just to catch possible logic problems as soon as I can, with objective-c being a dynamic language it seems to be a good practice to be careful, about stuff like this. I guess if it is not in code which call in some time critical part I would do as you do.